# Merging multiple .txt files in Google Colab

Tags: python, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I have around 500 .txt files in my local system and would like to merge them into a dataframe in Google Colab. I have already uploaded them via Upload option where I uploaded the zipped folder containing the .txt files and later unzipped them in Google Colab. Each .txt file has one row data eg. 0 12 34.3 423

I tried the following code to directly upload from my local system but it did not work

[image]

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: _but it did not work_ What does that mean, exactly? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colab cannot access your local files through the typical built-ins as far as I know. You have to use Colab-specific modules. The guide is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb).

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

This will prompt you to select the files to upload.

EDIT: As you need the file names, you can just use the loop above and then concatenate as you mentioned correctly.

```
# create a list of file names
file = []
for fn in uploaded.keys():
    files.append(fn)

# create a list of dataframes
for file in files:
        new = pd.read_csv(file)
        try:
            frames.append(new)
        except: 
            frames = [new] 

# concat all of your frames at once
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

Alternatively, depending on the size of your files, you could also join the for loops and load one file and concat it directly to the existing frames such that the memory has to hold less data at once.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I can upload the files in Google Colab using Upload option that you mentioned but then I have the problem of merging those individual files. For example I can use import option and use df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['text_01.txt'])) to convert file into dataframe and then concate all of them. The issue is I have around 500 files with different names

Comment: Just loop through your uploaded object and create a list of file names! I will edit the answer, one second.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. It was successful in combining the files and creating a dataframe.